# how to send and recieve notification using WPF and WCF

Tags: wpf, wcf, wcf-data-services

I am using WPF and WCF for client server application. but i got a problem.

How to notify any update of client to other client.

1. Server(WCF)
2. Client1(WPF)
3. Client2(WPF)

if client1 enter any new record,immediatly notification send to client2 .

please suggest me best way to this complete task.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

We have achieved such a requirement by using [WCF Duplex Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx). You can find enough information by googling about implementing a duplex service.

Basically;

- clients send a client identifier (uniquely generated for each client) while registering to duplex service.
- when WCF service updates data, pushes an update notification (including the notification source's client identifier) to all the registered clients
- clients check for the originator's identifier when they got a notification. Discarding notifications caused by itself.

A few notes:

- You can include everything about the updated data inside pushed notification payload to understand the change type or entity type.
- Different bindings supported by duplex services. Usage of nettcpbinding is suggested if clients and service are in the same network and .net dependency is not a problem. You can find more information about support binding types from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx) or [here](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/01/19/wcf-binding-comparision-list-and-supported-features-reference/).